# Wordpress : Changing text in the page with incoming URL variable parameter

Tags: wordpress

I would like to have a popup welcome mat in Wordpress which is able to show you custom texts.

The URL is supposed to look like this :

```
    http://thisisthedomain.com/post-name/?to=Mr.+John+Doe
```

The text will show "To: Mr. John Doe", and if you manually change the parameter in the URL, for example :

```
    http://thisisthedomain.com/post-name/?to=Ms.+Jane+Doe
```

The text in the popup welcome mat page will change into "To: Ms. Jane Doe".

How do I do this?

Comment: Hi @Nisa, welcome to Wordpress. Best to do a bit of your own research before posting here, and then providing more information (for example, how you are displaying the popup). As a starter, here's [some info on using URL parameters in WP](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/41370/using-get-variables-in-the-url/41373)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you're asking how to get the value of that query string (`?to=Ms.+Jane+doe`)

That'd be `$_GET['to']` - take a little look at https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php for some more information

http://thisisthedomain.com/post-name/?to=Mr.+John+Doe

```php
<?php
echo 'Hello ' . htmlspecialchars($_GET["to"]) . '!';
?>
```

Hello Mr. John Doe!

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation. I am able to solve the issue based on your answer. :)